# get user address in orders in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get user addresses in my orders edit page here is how it works:

1. User can have many address (one of them can be primary)
2. Order get user id
3. order get address id (addresses will loop base on user id from addresses table, so logged user cannot use other user address)

Here is issue:

I try to get addresses in my order edit page base on user id which is stored in orders table (it means get only addresses of person who saved this order and not all users)

this is my edit function code:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $order = Order::find($id);
        $users = User::all();
        $statuses = Orderstatus::all();
        $addresses = Address::where($order->user_id, '=', 'user_id')->get();
        return view('admin.orders.edit', compact('order', 'users', 'statuses', 'addresses'));
    }
```

this is error I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '5' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `addresses` where `5` = user_id)

This is my blade code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                    {{ Form::label('address_id', 'Shipping Address') }}
                    <select class="form-control" name="address_id">
                      @if(!empty($order->address_id))
                      @foreach($addresses as $address)
                      <option value="{{$address->id}}"  {{ $address->id == $order->address_id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$address->address}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                      @else
                      <option value="">Select Address</option>
                      @foreach($addresses as $address)
                        <option value="{{$address->id}}">{{$address->address}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Screenshots:

`address table`

[image: address]

`order table`

[image: orders]

> AS you can see in both `orders` and `addresses` table I have `user_id`
>   column, I want to match these 2 column together to get result.

## When Order->user_id is match with $address->user_id loop results.

any idea?

Comment: You can use relationships with models in Laravel like `belongsTo()`, `hasOne()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the `where` function jumbled.

It must be:

```
where('user_id', '=', $order->user_id)
```

and not the other way around. :)

Additionally, if you're using the `=` comparison, you can just leave it, because it is the default, so it can be like this:

```
where('user_id', $order->user_id)
```